# How do I get back these (occulted? Deleted?) rows?

Tags: google-sheets

Maybe this is closer to a superuser question, but since it involves scripting, all post my question here. I have a spreadsheet doc with a script (it's a very large one, so I'll avoid putting all code here) and some functions whith which I update a sheet from another uploaded and previous converted sheet. When I run it, it's turning some part of the rows of my data occult, this way:

[image]

How do I get back these (occulted? Deleted?) rows?

Thanks!

Comment: no idea about google spreadsheets, but if it was excel, you'd select the rows above/below the split point, and right-click->unhide

Comment: Select both rows, right click and unhide rows (2 to 109), if you are looking for amendment in your code, one would require your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not related to scripting.
You have a filter set in the first row. Remove or reset it.

Comment: Thanks, @Zig. I've tryied several things, but not that!